# Delphi equivalent code of C# extraction of Embedded Resource

Tags: c#, delphi, .net-assembly

I have found this code from [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_61pLVH2qPk), which shows how to extract embedded resources, with my modification that will extract from another application.

```
private static void Extract(string FileName, string nameSpace, string outDirectory, string internalFilePath, string resourceName)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(FileName);
        string ManifestString = nameSpace + '.' + (internalFilePath == "" ? "" : internalFilePath + ".") + resourceName;
        using (Stream s = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(ManifestString))
            using (BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(s))
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outDirectory + "\\" + resourceName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    using (BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                        w.Write(r.ReadBytes((int)s.Length));
    }
```

Do we have any Delphi equivalent code for this?

Comment: Typically you would use `TResourceStream`. But the resource mechanism is different. So it might depend on what your resource is and how you linked it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes I have tried `TResourceStream`, but I found it difficult to extract resource inside .net applications. as I have read that .net uses `.net-assembly`...

Comment: I don't understand. You are attempting to use Delphi code to extract a resource from a .net assembly?

Comment: Yes, if there's any?

Comment: Do mean [this](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicsprojects/resourceexplorer)?

Comment: @whosrdaddy No, that enumerates resources in an unmanaged module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you have two options.

1. Host the CLR, and call into it using the CLR API.
2. Create a .net class library and get that to do the work for you. Consume the .net class library from your Delphi code.

The first option is really no fun at all. The CLR API is very powerful, but also has a steep learning curve.

The second option is quite straightforward. Use C# and export functionality via COM, or perhaps with UnmanagedExports. That would allow you to use the code from the question. Or use a mixed model C++/CLI class library and expose classic unmanaged DLL exports that expose the functionality. This would require you to convert the code from the question into C++.